# How can i add the lines from the rectangle to the lines on this diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circuitikz

I want to finish this diagram but I don't know an efficient way to add three lines from each rectangle to the lines, to look like this:

[image: Example for what i want my diagram to look like.]

And this is what I've got so far and the code i used for it, using circuitikz:

[image: My current diagram]

And the code i used was:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        rect/.style={
            black,
            shape=rectangle,
            minimum width=3cm,
            minimum height=2cm,
            anchor=center},
        line/.style={
            black}
        ]
    
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro\linelength{13}
    
    \foreach \coordinate in {(0,0), (0,-0.7), (0,0.7)} 
    {
        \draw[line] \coordinate -- ++(0:\linelength);
    }
    
    \foreach \point in {1, 5, 9}
    {
        \draw[line] (\point,-3.5) rectangle ++(3,2) ;
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It's just minimal stuff, so a bit of help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

With `nodes` instead of rectangles and coordinates for lines, you can use intersection to draw the connections:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    carga/.style={draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm},
    connect/.style={-{Circle[]}, shorten > = -2pt},
    ]
    
    \node[carga] (carga1) {Carga 1};
    \node[carga, right=of carga1] (carga2) {Carga 2};
    \node[carga, right=of carga2] (carga3) {Carga 3};
    \draw ([shift={(-1cm,1cm)}]carga1.north west) coordinate (aux11)--([shift={(1cm,1cm)}]carga3.north east) coordinate(aux12);
    \draw ([yshift=.5cm]aux11) coordinate (aux21)--(aux21-|aux12);
    \draw ([yshift=.5cm]aux21) coordinate (aux31)--(aux31-|aux12);
    \draw[-Latex] ([xshift=.5cm]aux31) -- node[above, near end]{$I_T$} ++(.75,0);
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3}{
        \draw[connect] ([xshift=-5mm]carga\i.north) coordinate (aux) --(aux|-aux11);
        \draw[connect] (carga\i.north) coordinate (aux) --(aux|-aux21);
        \draw[connect] ([xshift=5mm]carga\i.north) coordinate (aux) --(aux|-aux31);
        \draw[Latex-] ([shift={(.5cm,.25)}]carga\i.north) -- node[right]{$I_\i$} ++(90:.5);
    }
    \draw[-Latex] ([xshift=.5cm]aux31) -- node[above, near end]{$I_T$} ++(.75,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution below uses a `foreach` loop inside a `foreach` loop. The first defines the main coordinates of each *carga*, the second draws each triple of lines.

The syntax `[count=\i]` enables a simple solution to add the counting inside the loop.

I remove the `rect` style since it wasn't being used. Currents `I_1` to `I_3` are drawn above the regular line with the connection dot, but a little bit below to be displayed where you want, the same applies to $I_T$.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  line/.style={
    black},
  ]
  
  %\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
  
  \pgfmathsetmacro\linelength{13}
  
  \draw (0,0.7) to[short, i=$I_T$] ++(1,0);
  
  \foreach \c/\p [count=\i] in {-0.7/1, 0/5, 0.7/9} {
    \draw[line] (0,\c) -- ++(0:\linelength);
    
    \foreach \x/\y in {1/-0.7, 1.5/0, 2/0.7} { 
      \draw (\p+\x,-1.5) to[short, -*] (\p+\x,\y);
    }
    \draw (\p+2,-0.8) to[short, i=$I_{\i}$] ++(0,-0.5);
  }
  
  \foreach \point [count=\i] in {1, 5, 9} {
    \draw[line] (\point,-3.5) rectangle ++(3,2) node[pos=0.5]{Carga \i};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]